# Delete folders owned by specific group?

Tags: 18.04, directory, delete, groups

I have loads of folders and files in the storage system, files and folders created by a specific group needs to be removed, but I can't find any smart quick way to do it. Not via find or anything.

Comment: Be careful when you run commands like this, some groups are necessary for certain system resources.

Comment: The find _dir_ -group _groupname_ -print command does not work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find` command for that

`find /location -group group_name -delete`

and yeah, please be careful with command as these. Before running just double & make sure that you know what you are doing.

Comment: Oh I have done my share of mistakes with these kinds of commands so no worries will be careful! Thanks!

Comment: @rɑːdʒɑ  you might want to add an `echo` or `-i`, so that other people unable to read won't just copy paste and harm their system...

Comment: @rɑːdʒɑ Strictly speaking you don't delete folders and files "created by" the group_name as asked by the OP, but folders and files "owned by" group_name. A group creates nothing.